# When to choose [^x]* or .*?

Tags: regex

Assume i have a substring in a longer string like (...)`aaabaacaaaaaXaaaadaeaa`(...) and i want to match or replace the `aaabaacaaaaa` with the `X` as delimiter.

I can now use (.*?)X to find the string before the `X` or i can use ([^X]*) to find it. I could also use negative look-ahead but i don't think it is necessary in this case.
So which one of the two (or three) options is the better technique to get the group i want to match in this context?

Comment: why you think that regexp is solution?

Comment: +1, I always had this question, and I tend to incline towards `[^X]*`.

Comment: Using a negated character class with a greedy quantifier is more performant than a dot with a lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this very simple example:

```
www\..*?\.com
www\.[^.]*\.com
```

The first one matches any input that contains a `www.` and a `.com` with anything in between. The second matches a `www.` and a `.com` that does not have a `.` in-between.

The first would match: `www.google.something.com`
The second would not.

Only use the negated class if that section absolutely cannot contain the character.

Comment: In the case of your example I would imagine it is entirely down to personal preference. Just remember that the 2 are not equivalent.

Comment: Why the '?' in the first example? At first you tell the RE to match whatever number of . (any character) by '*' and then you tell it by '?' to match only 0 or 1 repititions.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken `?` there doesn't stand for 0 or 1. Its a modifier (or whatever its called) that makes `.*` non-greedy.

Answer (score 2):

- `.*?` is called lazy quantifier.
- `[^X]*` is called greedy negation quantifier

Wherever possible use negation i.e. `[^X]` since it doesn't cause backtracking. Ofcourse if your input text can contain letter `X` then you have no choice but to use `.*?`

I am copying this text from one of the recent comment from @ridgerunner:

> The expression: `[^X)]*` is certainly more efficient than `.*?` in
>   every language except possibly Perl (whose regex engine is highly
>   optimized for the lazy dot star expression). The expression `.*?` must
>   stop and backtrack once at every character position as it
>   "bumps-along", whereas the greedy quantifier applied to the negated
>   character class expression can consume the entire chunk in a single
>   step, with no backtracking.